# Двойное отрицание - зачем оно нужно?

Tags: лингвистика

Извините, если вопрос глупый.
Но меня заинтересовало такое явление русского языка, как двойное отрицание. Например выражение "никого нет", "нигде нет" и т. д. В английском это все выражается одним словом: "nobody", "nowhere", "nothing" и т. д. И мне стало интересно, зачем вообще нужны двойные отрицания, как они появились и почему их нет в других языках?
И вопрос вдогонку: к какой категории вы посоветуете отнести этот вопрос (надо выставить метку, а я не знаю, какую выбрать)?

Answer (score 8):

Двойное отрицание - это не то, о чем Вы написали в вопросе. Если есть во фразе две одинаковые частицы НЕ - тогда да, отрицание двойное: оно соответствует утверждению. *Он не мог не сказать* = *он должен был сказать*.
При сочетании НЕ и НИ последняя частица является *не сама по себе* отрицающей, а усиливающей и уточняющей "главное глагольное отрицание" - в том смысле, что эта самая частица ***ни*** относится уже не к сказуемому (см. пример выше), а к дополнению или обстоятельству. *Старик никуда не пошел*. **Не пошел** куда? - В магазин? в лес? в баню? - Никуда, ни в один из всевозможных адресов.

Answer (score 7):

"Зачем нужны" - это вопрос не совсем удачный... Ни за чем не нужны. Они просто есть. Вернее сказать, есть нечто, что в русском принято называть "двойным отрицанием". Название, прямо скажем, совершенно неудачное. Двойное отрицание в математике, логике и т.п. это отрицание отрицания: "неправда, что Сократ не человек" влечет "Сократ - человек". Примерно в таком понимании этот термин используется большинством известных языков (кроме русского и некоторых других славянских).

В "правильном" английском, коли вы о нем упомянули, именно так все и понимается. "Nobody knows nothing" - вполне корректное выражение английского языка, которое и называется там "двойным отрицанием". Означает оно, что *кто-то что-то таки знает*. Такое построение фразы, понятно, не особо часто используется, но оно понятно и несет именно указанный смысл. - *Nobody knows nothing* хоть и похоже по форме на русское "никто ничего не знает" но означает *Somebody knows something*.

В русском же смысл другой. У нас по сути нет двойного отрицания, есть использование специальной усилительной частицы (в т. ч. слившейся с местоимением) при обычном одинарном отрицании. Да, эта частица когда-то развилась из отрицания, но не из "двойного" в математическом понимании, а из грамматики отрицания - отрицание при глаголах и остальных частях речи в древнерусском имело несколько разную грамматику. То, что было при глаголе, осталось отрицанием, а в остальных случаях превратилось в частицу.

Явление же, подобное русскому, также существует в некоторых языках (включая, по некоторым свидетельствам, техасский разговорный), но оно имеет несравнимо меньшее значение и распространение, на грани окказионализма, и обычно не называется двойным отрицанием.

Я в общем-то кратко, если нужно подробнее, напишите, мне немножко жалко времени и сил развивать эту мысль за рамки прямого ответа на вопрос.
(+)
Метками не заморачивайтесь, реально они нужны более для поисковиков, чем для людей. имхо. В случае чего - модератор поправит.

Answer (score 1):

Жаль, что я почти не знаю языков. Но точно знаю, что в итальянском языке (и, вероятно, во многих языках романской группы) точно так же, как в русском языке, используется "двойное отрицание". Например: "Non ho capito niente" дословно переводится "Я не понял ничего", и точно так же переводится по смыслу.

Answer (score 0):

Двойное отрицание в русском языке логически равно одинарному отрицанию. В английском, чтобы передать тот же смысл, отрицание бывает единственным. Но интересно, что испанский язык оказывается промежуточным случаем, где все зависит от порядка слов. В нем говорится "Никто знает" (одинарное отрицание) или "Не знает никто" (двойное ). Ну таковы свойства разных языков, приходится просто запоминать. Не ищите логики там, где древние люди ее не положили. Я вот никак не могу понять, почему месяц в обоих своих значениях мужского рода, а луна (слово не наше, но заимствовано с сохранением рода) имеет женский род.

Comment: "Не мог не сказать" - это двойное отрицание, дающее утверждение? Минус на минус даёт плюс. Или это что-то другое?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong. Nobody knows nothing - это не стандартный язык, а сознательная "ошибка" для придания языку "псевдонародности". Означает абсолютно то же, что Nobody knows anything.