# Что значит "никто не идеален"?

Tags: грамматика

По английски "nobody is perfect" означает что есть идеал но нет людей ему соответствующих. Всё логично. Я пытаюсь понять что даёт двойное отрицание в русском варианте? "Не идеален" означает человек с пороками. По идее, nobody is perfect, следует переводить как "вы не встретите идеального человека" или "любой человек не идеален" или "все люди не идеальны". Но никто не идеален, чисто логически означает что множество неидеальных пусто, то есть все идеальны. А мы как мне кажется мыслим под этим что-то прямо противоположнее. Всё правильно?

По английски "nobody is perfect" означает что есть идеал но нет людей ему соответствующих. Всё логично. Я пытаюсь понять что даёт двойное отрицание в русском варианте? "Не идеален" означает человек с пороками. По идее, nobody is perfect, следует переводить как "вы не встретите идеального человека" или "любой человек не идеален" или "все люди не идеальны". Но никто не идеален, чисто логически означает что множество неидеальных пусто, то есть все идеальны. А мы как мне кажется мыслим под этим что-то прямо противоположнее. Всё правильно?

То же самое относится и к "никто не без греха". 100 тыс совпадений в Гугле. "мы все не без греха" в 3 раза меньше. Это поному что у нас грамотрых людей во столько раз меньше?

Comment: Использование двойного отрицания не является признаком безграмотности. У языка своя логика - нужно донести смысл высказывания до слушателя, читателя. В [том же английском присутствуют подобные "нелогичные" конструкции](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative#English).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что двойные отрицания в русском языке работают не так, как в математике, и не так, как в некоторых других языках (например, в английском). Приведу простой пример. Фраза "Никто ничего не знает" означает, что ни один человек не обладает никакой информацией, а аналогичная (при дословном переводе) фраза "Nobody knows nothing" будет означать, что нет такого человека, который ничего не знает, т.е. каждый знает хоть что-то.

Происходит так, потому что частица НИ имеет не только отрицательное значение. Как говорит нам [Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B8), в утвердительном предложении в сочетании с местоименными или вопросительными словами означает истинность утверждения при любом варианте: "Кого я ни спрашивал, все говорили, что не знают его".

Эта тема [уже поднималась](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/38724/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE) здесь, поэтому можно воспользоваться поиском для получения дополнительных ссылок на источники и примеров.

Comment: Да, там хорошо сказали что "никто" имеет смысл усиления, а не восстановления инверсии.

Comment: @LittleAlien : *восстановления инверсии* - Вот это сказано плохо. ))) "Инверсия" - неуданый термин, если вне контекста. Хотя по сути - да, правильно.

Answer (score 2):

> Я пытаюсь понять что даёт двойное отрицание в русском варианте?

Здесь нет "двойного отрицания". Есть путаница. Попробую объяснить.

В русском языке под двойным отрицанием понимают отрицание отрицания, т.е.  конструкции типа "Не X не делал" или даже "Не не X". Означает - по принципу отрицания отрицания - то же, или почти то же, что без обоих отрицаний.

Кто сегодня не ходил на зарядку? Петя (не ходил)? - Нет, это не Петя не ходил (= Петя ходил).

Хотя такие конструкции в живом разговорном языке - большая редкость, иногда встречаются в языке книжном - и именно их следует называть "двойным отрицанием".

Ваш же пример двойным отрицанием не является. Если сопоставлять с английским языком, то "Никто" (ничто, нигде, никогда) означает отрицание только в редких случаях, когда опущен глагол. Тогда оно полностью соответвует английскому nobody (no one), в неполных ответах.
***Кто хочет ответить - Никто.

Who wants to answer? - Nobody (does).***

Во всех остальных случаях, т. е. с отрицанием при глаголе, "Никто"  - это "все", "любой", "каждый"  (=everyone, everybody, anyone, etc - depends on context).

***Никто не хочет ответить*** = (literally) ***Everyone does not want*** (=*nobody wants*).

Именно эта форма отрицания в русском (в отличие от английского) используется почти всегда. Никакого двойного отрицания тут нет и в помине, хотя иногда ошибочно так называют. Непривычно для иностранцев, но, если разобраться, в ней есть своя внутренняя логика и её можно понять и запомнить.